# I don't use \centering, but why must I use \arraybackslash in my table?

Tags: longtable

I don't use `\centering` or `\Centering` in my table below.

[image]

But I will get errors if I don't insert `\arraybackslash`.

Question:

1. What is `\arraybackslash` for? It seems so mysterious for me.
2. Why must I insert `\arraybackslash` in place labeled (3) that is shown in my code snippet below? Why must it be put in place (3) rather than (1), (2), or (4)?

---

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage[a4paper,margin=10mm,showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{lipsum,calc,xcolor}
\usepackage{array,longtable}
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{5mm}
\setlength{\arrayrulewidth}{5mm}

\newcolumntype{A}[1]
{%
        >{%                  
                \begin{minipage}{#1\textwidth-1.5\arrayrulewidth-2\tabcolsep}%
                \vspace{\tabcolsep}%
         }%
        c%
        <{%
            \vspace{\tabcolsep}%
             \end{minipage}%
         }%
}%
\begin{document}
\color{red}%
\begin{longtable}{%
    |%
        %>{\arraybackslash}%(1) => Not Needed 
        A{0.5}%
        %<{\arraybackslash}%(2) => Not Needed  
    |%
        >{\arraybackslash}% (3) => Mandatory!
        A{0.5}%
        %<{\arraybackslash}%(4) => Not Needed
    |%
}%
\hline
\lipsum[1] & \lipsum[2]\\\hline
\lipsum[1] & \lipsum[2]\\\hline
\lipsum[1] & \lipsum[2]\\\hline
\end{longtable}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Crosslink, related question explaining `\arraybackslash`: [line breaking - What is \arraybackslash doing on my table column? - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/387737/what-is-arraybackslash-doing-on-my-table-column)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

do not use the minipage, it does a lot of redefinitions. A p-column does the same:

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage[a4paper,margin=10mm,showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{lipsum,xcolor}
\usepackage{array,longtable}
\setlength\tabcolsep{5mm}
\setlength\arrayrulewidth{5mm}

\newcolumntype{A}[1]{>{\rule{0pt}{4ex}}p{\dimexpr#1\textwidth-1.5\arrayrulewidth-2\tabcolsep}%
                     <{\vspace{\tabcolsep}}}%
\begin{document}
\color{red}%
\begin{longtable}{|A{0.5}|A{0.5}|}\hline
\lipsum[1] & \lipsum[2]\\\hline
\lipsum[1] & \lipsum[2]\\\hline
\lipsum[1] & \lipsum[2]\\\hline
\end{longtable}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Did you mean `\hspace{\tabcolsep}`?

Comment: why did you use "asymmetric" vertical spaces--- `\rule{0pt}{4ex}` at the top but `\vspace{\tabcolsep}` at the bottom? Thanks.

Comment: Oh, I think I see what you're trying to do. You want the text to have a margin of `\tabcolsep` on all sides.

Comment: @TH, yes. I want the contents to be vertically and horizontally centered. And the tallest cell in a row will get the same 4 margins.

Comment: thanks for answering. I get your point. Forget `\arraybackslash` and always use `\tabularnewline`. But I insist on using minipage rather than `p{}` because I want to get symmetric margins and to allow the cells to be occupied by `\lstinputlisting` or `\begin{lstlisting}...\end{lstlisting}`.

Answer (score 15):

`\arraybackslash` resets the definition of `\\` to `\tabularnewline`.

```
\let\\\tabularnewline
```

The `minipage` environment changes the definition of `\\` (presumably), so `\arraybackslash` resets it.

Comment: But why must it be put in place (3) rather than (1), or (2), or (4)? See my code snippet above for the details. It is self-explanatory. :-) Thank you.

Comment: in short: in the last column TeX didn't know what `\\\` should be: a newline in the column or a new line of the tabular ...

Comment: @Herbert, why not in place (1) or (2) instead (if (4) does not make sense) ?

Comment: that depends to the array package and to the complecated environment in a tabular, because the \\  can also be used inside a math environment like `align`. However, it is a good idea to use `\tabularnewline` for a new tabularline.