# How to use \hlines and | column separators in a csv table uploaded with datatool

Tags: tables, datatool, database

Hi I've been trying to use the `datatool` package to get data from csv files easily into documents as formatted tables. I seem to keep getting the lines on the first column shifted down by a row.

If I rewrite the code so that it mimics the datatool manual `\DTLforeach` command I can't add the horizontal lines. What should I do differently? Am I missing something really obvious?

A supplementary question: If I want to use the `\DTLdecimaltolocale{item}{cmd}` to add thousands separators to the item lists in this database how can I do that? Thanks

[image: Two tables showing datatool misaligned csv]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array,datatool}

\begin{filecontents}{sample.csv}
account, opening balance, expected, revised, amends
fruit, 1000000,1500000,1750000,250000
berries, 400000,500000, 450000,-50000
nuts, 300000,375000,390000,15000
legumes, 1250000, 1000000, 950000, 50000
cereals, 800000, 80000, 90000, 10000
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[c]
\DTLloaddb[keys={ac,ob,ep,rv,df}]{dtl1}{sample.csv}
\caption{A Table to show misaligned borders}

\begin{tabular}{|p{4cm}|>{\raggedleft}p{2cm}|>{\raggedleft}p{2cm}|
>{\raggedleft}p{2cm}|>{\raggedleft}p{2cm}|}
\hline 
 & \bfseries 2010 Actual (a) & \textbf{2011 Target} & \textbf{2011
   Updated Plan (b)} &
\textbf{Difference (a) - (b)} \tabularnewline \hline \hline
\DTLforeach{dtl1}{\what=ac,\current=ob,\budget=ep,\plan=rv,\diff=df}{%
\what & \current & \budget & \plan & \diff \tabularnewline}
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\begin{table}
\caption{A Table to show misaligned borders working}
\begin{tabular}{|p{4cm}|>{\raggedleft}p{2cm}|>{\raggedleft}p{2cm}|
>{\raggedleft}p{2cm}|>{\raggedleft}p{2cm}|}
\hline
\bfseries account&\bfseries opening balance&\bfseries
expected&\bfseries revised&\bfseries amends\tabularnewline \hline \hline
fruit& 1000000&1500000&1750000&250000\tabularnewline
berries& 400000&500000& 450000&-50000\tabularnewline
nuts& 300000&375000&390000&15000\tabularnewline
legumes& 1250000& 1000000& 950000& 50000\tabularnewline
cereals& 800000& 80000& 90000& 10000\tabularnewline \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}


\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not an answer to your question but I also recommend [`pgfplotstable`](http://texdoc.net/pkg/pgfplotstable) for such constructions. You can then customize your output very easily using the key-value system as below.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array,booktabs}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}

\begin{filecontents}{sample.csv}
account, opening balance, expected, revised, amends
fruit,1000000,1500000,1750000,250000
berries,400000,500000, 450000,-50000
nuts,300000,375000,390000,15000
legumes,1250000,1000000, 950000,50000
cereals,800000,80000, 90000, 10000
\end{filecontents}

\pgfplotstableread[col sep=comma]{sample.csv}\mydata
\newcolumntype{d}{>{\raggedleft}b{2cm}}
\newcolumntype{e}{>{\raggedleft\arraybackslash}b{2cm}}
\begin{document}


\begin{table}
\caption{Fiscal Table of Breakfast Costs}
\pgfplotstabletypeset[
every head row/.style={before row={\toprule\hline},after row={\hline}},
every last row/.style={after row=\hline\bottomrule},
columns/account/.style         ={string type,column type={l},column name=Account},
columns/opening balance/.style ={column type={d},column name=Opening Balance},
columns/expected/.style        ={column type={d},column name=2011 Expected Target},
columns/revised/.style         ={column type={d},column name=2011 Updated Plan},
columns/amends/.style          ={column type={e},column name={Difference \textbf{(a) - (b)}}},
/pgf/number format/.cd,int detect,set thousands separator={,},
]\mydata
\label{tab:breakfast}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks @percusse 'pgfplotstable' was my next port of call to resolve this. Is there a way to add the column separator lines in this construction? What is the \arraybackslash in the column def doing by the way?

Comment: @TahnoonPasha Yes, it's just the usual `|` character that goes into the `column type` key but note that vertical seperators are often considered to be bad style in terms of informatics as they introduce artifical obstacles for the reader. For `\arraybackslash` see this question: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/7757/i-dont-use-centering-but-why-must-i-use-arraybackslash-in-my-table

Answer (score 2):

For the purposes of completeness I'm adding in a solution using `datatool`. It is more visually logical for me although I'm using `tikz` a lot so the tikz/`pgfplotstable` solution
that @percusse presented is clearly more flexible. I noticed a lot of datatool questions regarding format and data but no formatting answers. In case this is of some use..

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array,booktabs,datatool}

\begin{filecontents}{sample.csv}
account, opening balance, expected, revised, amends
fruit, 1000000,1500000,1750000,250000
berries, 400000,500000, 450000,-50000
nuts, 300000,375000,390000,15000
legumes, 1250000, 1000000, 950000, 50000
cereals, 800000, 80000, 90000, 10000
\end{filecontents}

\newcommand{\seps}[1]{\DTLdecimaltolocale{#1}{\tmp1}\tmp1}
\newcolumntype{d}{>{\raggedleft}b{2cm}}
\newcolumntype{e}{>{\raggedleft\arraybackslash}b{2cm}}
\DTLloaddb[keys={ac,ob,ep,rv,df}]{dtl1}{sample.csv}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}

\caption{A Table to show misaligned borders}
\begin{tabular}{|l|d|d|d|e|}
\toprule \hline 
 & \bfseries 2010 Actual (a) & \textbf{2011 Target} & \textbf{2011
   Updated Plan (b)} &
\textbf{Difference (a) - (b)}%
\DTLforeach{dtl1}{\what=ac,\current=ob,\budget=ep,\plan=rv,\diff=df}{%
\ifthenelse{\value{DTLrowi}=1}{\tabularnewline \hline}{\tabularnewline}
\what & \seps{\current} & \seps{\budget} & \seps{\plan} & \seps{\diff}}\\
\hline \bottomrule

\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]