# \raggedright has unusual behaviour in tables

Tags: tables, horizontal-alignment

I'm trying to make one column in a table appear ragged right. I've had some success, depending (inexplicably, to me) on the number of columns. The following works for me:

**Attempt 1**

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{dcolumn}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{l>{\everypar{\raggedright}}p{7cm}l}
a & This is a test to see how paragraphs behave in this table & x \\
b & Here's another line of the table, just for the fun of it & y
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Similarly, if I remove the first and third columns (leaving only the \raggedright column), then it still works.

However, I get errors and alignment problems when I remove the last column. In short, the following does not work:

**Attempt 2**

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{dcolumn}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{l>{\everypar{\raggedright}}p{7cm}}
a & This is a test to see how paragraphs behave in this table \\
b & Here's another line of the table, just for the fun of it
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Can anyone explain why one works but the other doesn't? Also, I couldn't get either to work without the dcolumn package, which seems strange to me because that should be unrelated. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Related/duplicate: [I don't use `\centering`, but why must I use `\arraybackslash` in my table?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/7757/5764)

Comment: Be *very* careful in using `\everypar`; in this case is not needed, as `\raggedright` is a declaration that keeps its effect in the whole current group.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is how you should be doing it.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{array}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{l>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{7cm}}
a & This is a test to see how paragraphs behave in this table \\
b & Here's another line of the table, just for the fun of it
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: However, `graphicx` is not needed.

Comment: @Dan Oh, yes. I missed it. Copy paste error. :-)