# Why do I need a second | at the end of my custom column description

Tags: tikz-pgf, tables, horizontal-alignment, equations

I just posted recently, it was marked duplicate, and a lot of the errors I made were corrected. Now, an updated question and the context

One issue I just noticed is that the tikzpicture isn't centered in the minipage in the table. How can I resolve this?

Using the below code, I noticed that I need to include a second | at the end of my column definition. If I don't, then I won't have the right column line. Unsure why?

Additionally, I'd like to know if there's a way to set the padding for the tikzpicture's minipage environment and the left/right equation column pair to be the same, so that the table size doesn't have to be manually controlled?

Context: I'm trying to make a two column table with a tikzpicture on the left and an equation on the right, aligned at the equality symbols. Utilizing [1](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/12703/how-to-create-fixed-width-table-columns-with-text-raggedright-centered-raggedlef), [2](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/7757/i-dont-use-centering-but-why-must-i-use-arraybackslash-in-my-table), and [3](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/78788/align-equations-over-multiple-tabular-rows), I have arrived at the following:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz,array,longtable,calc} % Not 100% sure if I actually need calc?
\newcolumntype{M}[1]
{
    >{
        \begin{minipage}{#1\textwidth-1.5\arrayrulewidth-2\tabcolsep}
        \vspace{\tabcolsep}
        \centering
    }
    c
    <{
        \vspace{\tabcolsep}
        \end{minipage}
    }
}
\newcolumntype{A}[1]
{%
    >{$}
        r
    <{$}
    @{\extracolsep{0pt}}
    >{${}}
        l
    <{$}
}%
\begin{document}
\begin{longtable}{| M{0.22} | A ||}
\hline
    \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=(current bounding box.center)]
        \draw [gray] (0,0) circle (15pt);
        \filldraw [gray] (0,0) circle (1pt);
        \draw [gray] (37.5pt,0) circle (15pt);
        \filldraw [gray] (37.5pt,0) circle (1pt);
    \end{tikzpicture} & \underline{2r_c \sin \left( ^{\pi} \!/ _{n_k} \right)}  &\geq  2r_f + R_1 r_f 
    \tabularnewline
\hline
    \begin{tikzpicture} [baseline=(current bounding box.center)]
        \draw [gray] (0,0) circle (15pt);
        \filldraw [gray] (0,0) circle (1pt);
        \draw [gray] (30pt,0) circle (15pt);
        \filldraw [gray] (30pt,0) circle (1pt);
    \end{tikzpicture} & 2r_c \sin \left( ^{\pi} \!/ _{n_k} \right)  &\leq   2r_f+\underline{R_1 r_f} \tabularnewline
\hline
    \begin{tikzpicture} [baseline=(current bounding box.center)]
        \draw [gray] (0,0) circle (15pt);
        \filldraw [gray] (0,0) circle (1pt);
        \draw [gray] (22.5pt,0) circle (15pt);
        \filldraw [gray] (22.5pt,0) circle (1pt);
    \end{tikzpicture} & 2r_c \sin \left( ^{\pi} \!/ _{n_k} \right)  &<   \underline{2r_f}+R_1 r_f \tabularnewline
\hline
    \begin{tikzpicture} [baseline=(current bounding box.center)]
        \draw [gray] (0,0) circle (15pt);
        \filldraw [gray] (0,0) circle (1pt);
        \draw [gray] (11.25pt,0) circle (15pt);
        \filldraw [gray] (11.25pt,0) circle (1pt);
    \end{tikzpicture} & 2r_c \sin \left( ^{\pi} \!/ _{n_k} \right)  &<   \underline{2r_f}+R_1 r_f \tabularnewline
\hline
\end{longtable}
\end{document}
```

Comment: In my continued efforts to properly center the tikz/minipage/longtable entry bonanza, I have arrived at the following and cannot find the options or lengths that affect the top or left margins of the graphics.

    \documentclass{article}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have

```
\newcolumntype{A}[1]
```

so your `A` column takes an argument (the first `|`) but discards it as there is no `#1` in the  definition.

Comment: Well that solves one question. Now to figure out why tikz isn't centered, and how to do auto-padding..